# mongodb query data to html drop down

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I have a mongo db that has countries and their associating cities.
I want to pull the countries from the db, and put that data in a HTML drop down selection list.

I have the below in `mongodbActions.js` used to connect to my mongodb instance, and do the querying and returning of the countries.

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
const Promise = require('rsvp').Promise;

// exporting functions
module.exports = {
    mongodbConn: async function() {
        try {
            // Connect to the mongodb server
            await client.connect();
            // Establish and verify connection
            await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
            console.log("Successfully connected to mongo DB.");

        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        } finally {
                await client.close();
                console.log("Successfully closed connection to mongo DB.");
        }
    },
    mongodbGetCountries: function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            const dbo = client.db('mydb').collection('countries_cities');
            let dbCountries = dbo.distinct('country', function(err, dbCountries) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);  
                } else {
                    resolve(dbCountries);
                }
            });
        });
    },
};
```

I made use of Promises, as using an async function, and trying to return the value, just resulted in a `Promise { <pending> }` when trying to access it in my `server.js`

And then I have `server.js` which has contents:

```
// load the express module
const express = require('express');
// load boad-parser module
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const mongodbActions = require('./static/scripts/mongodbActions')
console.log(mongodbActions)
// init db connection
mongodbActions.mongodbConn()

// get countries from db
let dbCountries = mongodbActions.mongodbGetCountries().then(function (items) {
    console.info('The promise was fulfilled with items!', items);
    return items
}, function(err) {
    console.error('The promise was rejected', err, err.stack);
});
console.log('server side countries:')
console.log(dbCountries)

const index = 'index.pug';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/static'));

// index page
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.url);
    // weather info / data -> display set to on
    let weatherVisibilty = 'visibility_on';
    let countryList = dbCountries
    res.render(index, { 
        countryList: countryList,
        setVisibility: weatherVisibilty 
    });
})
```

The below block of code displays the countries in a list, like I want.

```
// get countries from db
let dbCountries = mongodbActions.mongodbGetCountries().then(function (items) {
    console.info('The promise was fulfilled with items!', items);
    return items
}, function(err) {
    console.error('The promise was rejected', err, err.stack);
});
```

i.e.

```
The promise was fulfilled with items! [
  'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AI', 'AL', 'AM', 'AO', 'AQ', 'AR',
  'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AW', 'AX', 'AZ', 'BA', 'BB', 'BD', 'BE',
  'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BL', 'BM', 'BN', 'BO', 'BQ',
  'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'BW', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CA', 'CC', 'CD', 'CF',
  'CG', 'CH', 'CI', 'CK', 'CL', 'CM', 'CN', 'CO', 'CR', 'CU',
  'CV', 'CW', 'CX', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DJ', 'DK', 'DM', 'DO',
  'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'EH', 'ER', 'ES', 'ET', 'FI', 'FJ',
  'FK', 'FM', 'FO', 'FR', 'GA', 'GB', 'GD', 'GE', 'GF', 'GG',
  'GH', 'GI', 'GL', 'GM', 'GN', 'GP', 'GQ', 'GR', 'GS', 'GT',
  'GU', 'GW', 'GY', 'HK', 'HN', 'HR', 'HT', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE',
  ... 146 more items
]
```

However the below block, which I would like it to be the value of `items` from above.

```
console.log('server side countries:')
console.log(dbCountries)
```

Returns the below:

```
server side countries:
Promise {
  _id: 1,
  _label: undefined,
  _state: undefined,
  _result: undefined,
  _subscribers: []
}
```

So that is **NOT** the list of countries I want.

Which I want to pass to my pug file: `index.pug` to be the contents of my drop down selection list.

Please note that I am quite a noob with javascript and mongodb.

Your assistance and guidance will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the data from async function outside the scope of that function itself. You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/7482427) on SO to better understand how async calls work.

That's why `console.log(dbCountries)` always return the promise.

I would suggest you to use `async/await` and modify your `GET` route

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url);
    // weather info / data -> display set to on
    let weatherVisibilty = 'visibility_on';

    let dbCountries = await mongodbActions.mongodbGetCountries();
    let countryList = dbCountries

    res.render(index, { 
        countryList: countryList,
        setVisibility: weatherVisibilty 
    });
})
```

Comment: awesome thank you. I thought I may have to do something like that.
just wasn't sure about being able to use the returned data outside the scope of an asynchronous function.
thanks for clarifying that.